# create a dummy variable (using mutate) based on a pattern in a character string

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I'm trying to figure out how to create a dummy variable based on a pattern in a character string.  The point is to end up with a simple way to make certain aspects of my ggplot (color, linetype, etc.) the same for samples that have something in common (such as different types of mutations of the same gene -- each sample name contains the name of the gene, plus some other characters).

As an example with the iris dataset, let's say I want to add a column (my dummy variable) that will have one value for species whose names contain the letter "v", and another value for species that don't.  (In the real dataset, I have many more possible categories.)

I've been trying to use `mutate` and `recode`, `str_detect`, or `if_else`, but can't seem to get the syntax right.  For instance,

```
mutate(iris, 
    anyV = ifelse(str_detect('Species', "v"), "withV", "noV"))
```

doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't detect that any of the species names contain a v, either.  Which I think has to do with my inability to figure out how to get `str_detect` to work:

```
iris %>% 
  select(Species) %>%
  str_detect("setosa")
```

just returns `[1] FALSE`.

```
iris %>% 
  filter(str_detect('Species', "setosa"))
```

doesn't work, either.

(I've also tried things like a mutate/recode solution, based on an example in [7 Most Practically Useful Operations When Wrangling Text Data in R](https://blog.exploratory.io/7-most-practically-useful-operations-when-wrangling-with-text-data-in-r-7654bd9d1a0c)  , but can't get that to work, either.)

What am I doing wrong?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: Use `anyV = ifelse(str_detect(Species, "v"), "withV", "noV")`. (Don't put quotes around Species otherwise you are just testing that string, not the Species column)

Comment: Aha, thanks!  I get hopelessly confused about when to use quotes and when not to; probably one of those places where some actual programming background would come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
library(stringr)
iris%>% mutate(
    anyV = ifelse(str_detect(Species, "v"), "withV", "noV"))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  anyV
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa   noV
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa   noV
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa   noV
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa   noV
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa   noV
...
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor withV
53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor withV
54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor withV
55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor withV
56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor withV
57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor withV
58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor withV
59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor withV
```

An alternative to nested `ifelse` statements:

```
iris%>% mutate(newVar = case_when(
    str_detect(.$Species, "se") ~ "group1",
    str_detect(.$Species, "ve") ~ "group2",
    str_detect(.$Species, "vi") ~ "group3",
    TRUE ~ as.character(.$Species)))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'd tried so many combinations of things, and none of them was syntactically quite right.

Comment: Also, as a note to future users, this is a place where `case_when` looks like it will be incredibly helpful.  `ifelse` is great, but when (like in my real dataset) you have a whole string of ifelses to deal with, the `case_when` syntax is going to be much more readable and user-friendly!

Comment: @phosphorelated Also, be aware that in the next dplyr version (0.6.0), you will not have to use `.$` in front of the column name inside `case_when`